# Multiprocessing Windows: how to prevent rerun?

Tags: windows, python-3.x, multiprocessing, spyder

I'm using this multiprocessing script:

**Test class**

```
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool

class Test:

    def __init__(self):
        print("init")

    def getData(self, x, ID):
        return x + str(ID)

    def process(self):
        pool = Pool(processes=10)
        IDList = range(10)
        data = []
        for ID in IDList:
            async_result = pool.apply_async(self.getData, ("wordl", ID))
            data.append(async_result.get())
        return data
```

**main script**

```
from TestClass import Test

def main():
    test = Test()
    test.process()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I run this the file, it keeps running. I found out that Windows is the problem here:

> Just figured out the problem with this on Win 7 anaconda pyscripter
>   2.6.0 Pyscripter generates a .pyc file which is what is rerun everytime u run the  program, just deleted it and it worked fine for me ([source](https://github.com/pyscripter/pyscripter/issues/722))

Is there a way to add code to this script so it will work on Windows? I tried using `sys.dont_write_bytecode = True`, but this didn't work.

Comment: There are repeated examples and warnings in the multiprocessing documentation that creating processes needs to be protected by an `if __name__ == '__main__'` check for Windows.

Comment: Thankyou so much! Can this be used inside a function as well? @eryksun

Comment: This is because I want to use it in a function inside a class @eryksun

Comment: When multiprocessing runs the main script in the child process, it uses the name `"__mp_main__"` instead of `"__main__"`, which avoids recursively creating processes when gated by checking for `"__main__"`. The `__name__` check can be used anywhere in the script; it's a global value in the module, but it's typical to just have a single check that calls a `main()` function. From there you can call functions or methods in the main script or in other modules that create processes.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you are saying but use the if __main__ (or the __mp_main__) check inside the fetchfunction(see edited code) will print "main error". Note that this is a function inside a class. @eryksun

Comment: The main script is what you run from the command line, e.g. `python mainscript.py`. It looks like you're showing part of a class definition. Is that class defined in the main script? If not, why would you expect the `__name__` to ever be `"__main__"`?

Comment: No the class definition is not in the main script, only an instance is made of this class in the mainscript. I don't expected it to be but I tried what you said what should I use instead then? Is this even possible?@eryksun

Comment: It's ok if a method in another module creates processes. But calling it should flow from statements in the main script that execute only when its `__name__` is `"__main__"`. In Windows, the script and imported modules get executed for every child process because multiprocessing has to spawn a new process from scratch. The main script's name is changed to `"__mp_main__"` to avoid blowing up recursively when it's executed in a child process, given the `"__main__"` check. In Unix it's not a problem because multiprocessing forks a child process that shares the same state as the parent.

Comment: I appreciate your help but it's still not working :( I added a simple (but full) code example hopefully you can see what is going on @eryksun This code will just keep running

Comment: How are you running this? It works fine for me in Python 3 when run from the command prompt. Obviously it doesn't work in Python 2 since methods aren't pickleable.

Comment: You are right that's strange running it from the command line (Python 3.6.0 :: Anaconda 4.3.1) works fine but when I run it using spyder (also python 3.6 offcourse) will not work (keeps running) @eryksun

Comment: Are you using an IPython console in spyder? There's an [open issue](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/1900) for that.

Comment: hmm that is the problem then... this issue is open since 2015 so I think I will stick to the command line then hahaha thankyou for all your help anyway! @eryksun